# Specifying nested dictionary key in list of arguments

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, key

I have a function which iterates over a list of dicts, returning specified key-value pairs into a new list of dicts:

```
data = [
    {'user': {'login': 'foo1', 'id': 'bar2'}, 'body': 'Im not sure', 'other_field': 'value'},
    {'user': {'login': 'foo2', 'id': 'bar3'}, 'body': 'Im still not sure', 'other_field': 'value'},
]

filtered_list = []
keys = ['user','body']

for i in data:
    filt_dict = dict((k, i[k]) for k in keys if k in i)
    filtered_list.append(filt_dict)
```

The `user` key contains a sub-key called `login`; how can this be added to the keys argument list, instead of the key `user`?

Sample output:

```
filtered_list = [
    {'login': 'foo1', 'body': 'Im not sure'},
    {'login': 'foo2', 'body': 'Im still not sure'},
]
```

Comment: How exactly shall the output look like for the pseudocode `keys`?

Comment: See the above edit.

Comment: Can we change the `keys` structure to a list of tuples? Eg, `[('user', 'login'), ('body',)]`

Comment: Yes that would be fine, except just with the login field, e.g. ('login', 'body').

Comment: BTW, you should fix the quotes in your body strings.

Comment: It's simpler to make all the keys tuples. Dealing with a mixture of tuples and strings is a bit messier, and slower, because you have to call the `isinstance` function.

Comment: Okay, how can the desired output be achieved using that method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this? Assumes your chain of keys actually exists in the dicts you are iterating.

Setup

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> data = [{'user': {'login': 'foo1', 'id': 'bar2'}, 'body': 'Im not sure', 'other_field': 'value'},
...         {'user': {'login': 'foo2', 'id': 'bar3'}, 'body': 'Im still not sure', 'other_field': 'value'}]
>>> keys = [('user', 'login'), ('body',)]
```

Solution

```
>>> [{ks[-1]: reduce(dict.get, ks, d) for ks in keys} for d in data]
[{'body': 'Im not sure', 'login': 'foo1'}, {'body': 'Im still not sure', 'login': 'foo2'}]
```

Comment: I'm marking Ralf's as the correct answer due to it's simplicity, however your code also worked so thanks for the effort.

Comment: @LaurieBamber I was assuming that you want the code to work for *any* list of keys. If you can hardcode the keys, my answer is too complicated. If you can't hardcode the keys, the other answer won't get you far. ;)

Comment: @LaurieBamber This code handles a `keys` list of any length, and nested dicts of any depth. Ralph's answer is fine, but it's locked in to the specific structure shown in the question, so if you need to handle different keys you have to edit the code.

Comment: This is a great response

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain, that all elements (dicts) in the list will have the keys you specified, then a quick solution could be this:

```
filtered_list = [
    {
        'login': elem['user']['login'],
        'body': elem['body'],
    }
    for elem in data]
```

This has no error handling for missing keys.